# Update all packages on Pycharm

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

Is there any way to update all the packages on pycharm community version? Currently I only can update them one by one and I have a lot of outdated packages!

I do not have a conda environment and use the install python on my Windows 10.

Comment: there's a zero dep package that does that: [pipupgrade](https://github.com/achillesrasquinha/pipupgrade). Of course if you have `git bash` (because Windows) then you could also try something crazy with xargs, pipe, etc

Comment: So, the short answer is No. If it was Linux, I could write a bash script to get all packages by `pip list` and then just iterate over them and run `pip install --upgrade`. But, In windows I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: pipupgrade or you could just write a simple python script for that then!

Answer (score 6):

I wanted to update all packages in one shot, I'm currently using pycharm professional version by student license. I'm not sure that this approach can be applied on your Pycharm since our versions are different, but I want to share my experience.

Go to [File > Settings] and choose the interpreter which you'd wanted to upgrade its packages, and pick packages with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Left Click</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Left Click</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, and click the update button (triangle icon).

Answer (score 1):

You could run

```
pip list --outdated
```

from the terminal windows in PyCharm. This will list all the packages that need to be updated.

Edit this list to do a "pip install --upgrade", appending the list.

Answer (score 0):

In windows I did it something different:

Go to [File > Settings] and choose the interpreter which you'd wanted to upgrade its packages, and pick packages with Ctrl + left mouse button and them click the triangle at top of screen sided with + and -.

Comment: Not sure this is how you should do it. I marked all and press this triangle, after that the whole venv broke.

Comment: I've learned that python is not friendly concerning updates, use of packages etc. In some systems tutorials work in other they don't. It worked for me.  Sorry it didn't for you.